# React Query, useQuery returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

Hello mighty developers,

I find myself in the following issue:

I have a hook called useMembers declared in a "util" file:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { customApi } from 'services/api';

export const useMembers = async ({ myId }) => {
  const {
    data: response, error, isError, isLoading,
  } = await useQuery(
    `endpoint-${myId}`,
    async () => {
      const bigMembers = await customApi.get(`one/lovely/endpoint`);
      return {
        ...bigMembers,
        data: {
          ...bigMembers.data,
          members: bigMembers.data,
        },
      };
    },
    {
      cacheTime: 0
    }
  );
  const memberList = response && response.data && response.data.members || []
    console.log(memberList) //return an array with 2 items;
  return {
    members: memberList,
    error,
    isError,
    isLoading,
    status: response?.status,
  };
};
export default useMembers;
```

In the Main Component file, I'm calling my hook but it gives undefined:

```
const {  members, error : errorOnMembers, isLoading: isLoadingOnMembers } = useMembers({ myId });
console.log({members}) //undefined;
```

I can't figure out why it gives undefined, should be an empty array at least

Comment: can you try to return response and check if the data is correct on `response.data.members`?

Comment: why are you `await`ing `useQuery`? It does not return a Promise.

Comment: @trixn . Thank you! It fixed the problem, give it as an official answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `await` `useQuery`. React hooks are generally never async functions as they have to be called synchronously during render. Remove the `async` from `useMembers` and the `await` in front of `useQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a variable in your fetch function that will store your data. Like this:

```
 const fetchAll = async () => {
    let fetchData;
    await axios.get(`/some/route/over/there`).then((res) => (fetchData = res.data));
    return fetchData;
  };
```

I'm using axios here but this should work with any http request.
What's happening is there's a variable that react must check twice before rendering to page.